# How to check error message in C#?

Tags: c#, testing, assertion

Is that a way to check error message shown after negative values? I can check if the correct exception was thrown, but what if my method won't throw an exception with negative numbers, just WriteLine to Error output stream.

```
public List<int> MyMethod()
{
    ...
    try
    {
        //add elements to list
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Error.WriteLine("Element cannot be negative, but other elements are ok");
    }
    ...
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestWithNegatives()
{
    try
    {
        List<int> list = MyMethod();
        //there is a negative int in list, so there'll be an error message
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Can I check here the error message, if there isn't exception thrown in mymethod?
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried unit tests?

Comment: What does "display" mean. You have a GUI, a console application?

Comment: Writing a bunch of lines to the console to be displayed in various situations is or can be a simple but functional way to go. Similarly you can set breakpoints and inspect the elements as you go along with a debug, that might save you alot of if statements for the console.

Comment: @programmo you surely can, it is hard to say how without seeing the code though. You could improve your question by adding a code sample of your method and unit test

Comment: @BojanB sure, I added my code

Comment: @programmo, still a bit hard to work with the example, but I'll try to give some pointers. (FYI, this what I would do, it might not be the best solution in the context). Remove the `try catch` from both methods. In your `MyMethod` check if the element is negative and if it is, instead of writing out the error, throw an exception. Then handle it where it is called. As for the test - after removing the try catch, just assert that an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already handled the exception and it is not rethrown, you cannot handle it again in your test.

But since you know that a message is written to `Console.Error`, you can check this by redirecting `Console.Error` to a custom `StringWriter` and check what was written to it like that:

```
public void TestWithNegatives()
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        Console.SetError(sw);
        List<int> list = MyMethod();
        // Check output in "Error":
        Assert.IsFalse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sw.ToString())); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's what I needed.